# Do I need to run artisan make:auth command to use Auth facade

Tags: laravel

I'm new to Laravel.

Do we need to run "php artisan make:auth" command to use Auth facade?
I don't need laravel's pre-built views and controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No You don't need to run " php artisan make:auth " to use the Auth facade.

make:auth command just creates views and other stuff so you don't have to create that. It includes login and registration process.

Auth Facade is the facade that gives you the information about authenticated user.

For more detail read the larvel documentation

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication